# Adding a Generated QR Code from Google Sheet to an Avery "Mail merge" template in Google Docs

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, qr-code, google-docs-addon

Using the [Avery Google Docs Add-on](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/avery-label-merge/onacejilpbdgdhhoijnggpjolbdajepo)  I am attempting to make some labels with QR codes on them.

You will need to open Google Docs then install the add-on in docs. you will also need a spreadsheet with a couple columns and rows of data to use it.

In my case; I can use the deprecated Google Docs Chart and a free QR Code API to create QR codes in Google Sheets. Both using the same `=IMAGE(URL, [mode], [height], [width])` formula. 
For example

```
=IMAGE("https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=100x100&data="&ENCODEURL(A2),3)
```

and

```
=IMAGE("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl="&ENCODEURL(A2),3)
```

Cell A2 holds the data I want in the QR Code.

[Example Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wf3ApEgUsgLesfpO83Uy5vnNvIHLKuDpqbvyM-XeMxY/edit?usp=sharing)
The Avery add-on doesn't seem to add the QR Codes from either column. It just creates a table to match the Avery template with any text I've included.  Nothing more.  I have found manually copy-pasting works but that defeats the purpose of a merging app.

Does anyone have any other methods to auto-merge QR codes from google sheets or other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a limitation of Google Docs, not add-on Avery Label Merge. The issue is that Google Document is unable to read **`=IMAGE()`** formula from Google Spreadsheet, therefore not auto-importing any images (while mare 1-by-1 copy/paste works).

[image]